# Command Line Rename of directories with wildcard at the end

Tags: command-line, rename

I have some folders, such as

```
John Doe - 03 November 2020 1234
John Doe - 03 November 2020 1259
Jane Doe - 03 November 2020 1234
```

I want to rename these folders with a prefix (ex: "1_" or a "2_", depending on other information). I'm trying to use code such as this to take advantage of either the * or ? wildcards, but it doesn't seem to work the way I intend.

```
ren "John Doe*" "1_John Doe*"
ren "John Doe????????????????????????" "1_John Doe????????????????????????"
```

But when I try to incorporate the wild card to incorporate the last three digits everything fails

```
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
```

This works fine when I rename folders without a variable ending to them, but then I have multiple folders with the same names, so that's not a possible solution.

```
John Doe - 03 November 2020

ren "John Doe - 03 November 2020" "1_John Doe - 03 November 2020"

1_John Doe - 03 November 2020
```

Suggestions welcome.

Comment: I would suggest Powershell.  To help more, I think we would need to know what `depending on other information` means.

Comment: I'm passing the command in from another program where I'm pulling data. The command in the last box above works directly in cmd.exe or in my other program. I'm honestly not sure if it's running in cmd.exe or in Powershell. When I pass through the "dir" command it shows a bright blue background that makes me think it's Powershell, but I'm not totally sure.

Answer (score 0):

In powershell you can use:

```
Get-ChildItem ./* -Directory | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.name -replace '\w*^', '1_'}
```

The two bits of text between the single 's are regular expressions. To insert "2_" to the start of the filename, just change the command to:

```
Get-ChildItem ./* -Directory | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.name -replace '\w*^', '2_'}
```

To insert a three before the filename change the 2 to a 3, and so on.

Comment: Where `2_` Will take place?

Comment: This appears to rename files in directories. I'm trying to rename directories. I'm also trying to pass the 1_, or 2_ or 456_ in from a dataset I have set up with these file names, so I don't think this will work for me.

Comment: The "-Directory" switch parameter restricts the renaming to ONLY affecting directories, because only directories are passed to rename-item. Give it a try, it worked for me when I tested it.